# How to display result in textbox using jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, textbox

I have one jsp form in which I am accepting product quantity and product rate from user and multiplication of that I want to show in textbox when I click on Calculate button. How would I achieve this using jsp servlet. I tried using javascript but it doesnt work.

Can u please suggest me something?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

    function NetAmount() 
    {
        //alert("Iam in java script");

         var pquantity= document.getElementById("prodquantity").value; // document.f11.prodquntity.value; 
         var prate = document.getElementById("prodrate").value; //document.f11.prodrate.value; 

         var neta = parseInt(pquantity) * parseDouble(prate);

            document.getElementById("netamount").value = neta;

    }

</script>
```

Comment: As your quantity and product rate are on page itself you just need to calculate them through Javascript itself and set it to text box.

Check this, its little bit different but the same way you can calculate the price http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528892/using-forms-in-html-to-calculate-total-price

Comment: Sir I have tried using javascript but it doesnt work

Comment: Please double check your element id and make sure there is no javascript error while you are performing Calculation. Its plain java script so it should work.

Comment: Are you using the correct element's ids?  The value of *neta* is right? Your issue is just how to show the value of neta into the textarea *netaamount*  ?

Comment: Check here a small working example based on your function NetAmount, compare it with what you have in your local machine. It should be straight foward.

http://jsfiddle.net/ggev1asy/

Comment: Can you show entire code and not just javascript. Also indicate what is not working? Is it throwing any error OR it is not able to calculate value OR is it not assigning the value? Please be specific.

Comment: Thank u so much Shaikh Mohammed Shariq its working.