# Trying to create a timesheet using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528892/using-forms-in-html-to-calculate-total-price) via Google. I am trying to build a timesheet that will calculate total hours.

When trying the linked post, it won't calculate. To make matters worse... I truly don't know what I am doing so I am literally hacking at the above code.

Thanks

```js
function calculateTime(){

  //Get selected data  
  var elt = document.getElementById("supthu1a");
  var supthu1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supfri1a");
  var supfri1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supsat1a");
  var supsat1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supmon1a");
  var supmon1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("suptue1a");
  var suptue1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supwed1a");
  var supwed1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supthu2a");
  var supthu2 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supfri2a");
  var supfri2 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supsat2a");
  var supsat2 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supmon2a");
  var supmon2 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("suptue2a");
  var suptue2 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("supwed2a");
  var supwed2 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
  

  //convert data to integers
  supthu1 = parseInt(supthu1a);
  supfri1 = parseInt(supfri1a);
  supsat1 = parseInt(supsat1a);
  supmon1 = parseInt(supmon1a);
  suptue1 = parseInt(suptue1a);
  supwed1 = parseInt(supwed1a);
  supthu2 = parseInt(supthu2a);   
  supfri2 = parseInt(supfri2a);
  supsat2 = parseInt(supsat2a);
  supmon2 = parseInt(supmon2a);
  suptue2 = parseInt(suptue2a); 
  supwed2 = parseInt(supwed2a); 
   
  //calculate total value  
  var total = supthu1+supfri1+supsat1+supmon1+suptue1+supwed1+supthu2+supfri2+supsat2+supmon2+suptue2+supwed2; 
  
  //print value to  PicExtPrice 
  document.getElementById("PicExtHours").value=total;

}
```

```html
<FORM Name="Timesheet">
  
<form action='' method='post'>
<p><label>Name</label><br><input type='text' name='name' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Employee Number:</label><br><input type='text' name='empnumber' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Department</label><br><input type='text' name='dept' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Pay Period Ending</label><br><input type='text' name='ppend' value=''></p> 
<br>
<p>
 
 <label>Support</label>
 <br>
 <label>Thu</label><input type='number' name='supthu1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supthu1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Fri</label><input type='number' name='supfri1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supfri1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Sat</label><input type='number' name='supsat1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supsat1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Mon</label><input type='number' name='supmon1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supmon1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Tue</label><input type='number' name='supteu1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="suptue1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Wed</label><input type='number' name='supwed1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supwed1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Thu</label><input type='number' name='supthu2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supthu2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Fri</label><input type='number' name='supfri2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supfri2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Sat</label><input type='number' name='supsat2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supsat2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Mon</label><input type='number' name='supmon2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supmon2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Tue</label><input type='number' name='suptue2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="suptue2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Wed</label><input type='number' name='supwed2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supwed2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
</p> 
</FORM>
<button type="button" onclick="calculateTime()">Calculate</button>
Total Hours:<INPUT type="text" id="PicExtHours" Size=8>
 
<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
var elt = document.getElementById("supthu1a");
var supthu1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
```

supthu1a here is an input tag, and it looks like what you are doing is getting the value of a select/dropdown box.

All you need should here is:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("supthu1a");
var supthu1 = elt.value;
```

2.
In the //convert data to integers bit you are taking supthu1a and trying to parse an int. supthu1a does not exist at this point, so you get NaN returned for each of these. You need to remove the trailing a at the end of each of these:

```
supthu1 = parseInt(supthu1);
supfri1 = parseInt(supfri1);
//and so on
```

3.
Each of these have onchange="calculateTime()". This is fine, except that when no value is present in the input boxes, the parse int for that input will return NaN, and your addition will fail. This only works once each box contains a number.
You can correct this a number of ways, but the easiest may be something like:

```
supthu1 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supthu1))? parseInt(supthu1):0);
supfri1 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supfri1))? parseInt(supfri1):0);
//and so on
```

4.
What you did up top with the variable elt is ok in JavaScript, but it could be a problem in other languages, and is generally avoided. You only need to declare var elt = something once. After that, you can reassign things to it with just elt = something. Better yet, you can avoid using it completely by changing the beginning to this format:

```
var supthu1 = document.getElementById("supthu1a").value;
var supfri1 = document.getElementById("supfri1a").value;
//and so on
```

Again, what you had is ok here and perfectly valid, just unconventional.

5.
This is preferences as well, but you can omit the onchange attributes if you'd like from each of the input tags and replace it all in javascript with just a few lines:

```
//Plain JavaScript
window.onload = function(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(){calculateTime();});
    }
}

//jQuery way of things
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=number]').change(function(){calculateTime();})};
});
```

6.
One last minor thing - you specify size="3" for each of the inputs. Size is inconsistent across different browsers and their possible font settings. I realize that since this is unstyled(so far, anyways) it doesn't matter so much, but as far as I know, this is bad practice. Commonly, you'll see input sizes set with a 100% width in the css, and defining the width of a parent div for the input to show how wide the field should be. Bootstrap follows this approach.

So, all together, we have:

```js
 
window.onload = function(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
     inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(){calculateTime();});
    }
}

function calculateTime(){

  //Get selected data  
  var supthu1 = document.getElementById("supthu1a").value;
  var supfri1 = document.getElementById("supfri1a").value;
  var supsat1 = document.getElementById("supsat1a").value;
  var supmon1 = document.getElementById("supmon1a").value;
  var suptue1 = document.getElementById("suptue1a").value;
  var supwed1 = document.getElementById("supwed1a").value;
  var supthu2 = document.getElementById("supthu2a").value;
  var supfri2 = document.getElementById("supfri2a").value;
  var supsat2 = document.getElementById("supsat2a").value;
  var supmon2 = document.getElementById("supmon2a").value;
  var suptue2 = document.getElementById("suptue2a").value;
  var supwed2 = document.getElementById("supwed2a").value;
  
  //convert data to integers
  supthu1 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supthu1))? parseInt(supthu1):0);
  supfri1 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supfri1))? parseInt(supfri1):0);
  supsat1 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supsat1))? parseInt(supsat1):0);
  supmon1 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supmon1))? parseInt(supmon1):0);
  suptue1 = (!isNaN(parseInt(suptue1))? parseInt(suptue1):0);
  supwed1 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supwed1))? parseInt(supwed1):0);
  supthu2 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supthu2))? parseInt(supthu2):0);   
  supfri2 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supfri2))? parseInt(supfri2):0);
  supsat2 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supsat2))? parseInt(supsat2):0);
  supmon2 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supmon2))? parseInt(supmon2):0);
  suptue2 = (!isNaN(parseInt(suptue2))? parseInt(suptue2):0); 
  supwed2 = (!isNaN(parseInt(supwed2))? parseInt(supwed2):0);
   
  //calculate total value  
  var total = supthu1+supfri1+supsat1+supmon1+suptue1+supwed1+supthu2+supfri2+supsat2+supmon2+suptue2+supwed2; 
  
  //print value to PicExtPrice 
  document.getElementById("PicExtHours").value=total;
}
```

```html
<FORM Name="Timesheet">
  
<form action='' method='post'>
<p><label>Name</label><br><input type='text' name='name' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Employee Number:</label><br><input type='text' name='empnumber' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Department</label><br><input type='text' name='dept' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Pay Period Ending</label><br><input type='text' name='ppend' value=''></p> 
<br>
<p>
 
 <label>Support</label>
 <br>
 <label>Thu</label><input type='number' name='supthu1' id="supthu1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Fri</label><input type='number' name='supfri1' id="supfri1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Sat</label><input type='number' name='supsat1' id="supsat1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Mon</label><input type='number' name='supmon1' id="supmon1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Tue</label><input type='number' name='supteu1' id="suptue1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Wed</label><input type='number' name='supwed1' id="supwed1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Thu</label><input type='number' name='supthu2' id="supthu2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Fri</label><input type='number' name='supfri2' id="supfri2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Sat</label><input type='number' name='supsat2' id="supsat2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Mon</label><input type='number' name='supmon2' id="supmon2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Tue</label><input type='number' name='suptue2' id="suptue2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Wed</label><input type='number' name='supwed2' id="supwed2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
</p> 
</FORM>
<button type="button" onclick="calculateTime();">Calculate</button>
Total Hours:<INPUT type="text" id="PicExtHours" Size=8>
 
<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p> 
</form>
```

Comment: Also, as @Serlite pointed out, nested form elements are invalid, so remove the outer form as well, too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the code you provide that prevent it from having a basic level of functionality. I've made corrections to your code as follows:

**HTML corrections:**

- HTML `<form>` elements [cannot be nested](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element), so I combined them into
  a single `<form>` with both their attributes.
- You assigned a default value of an empty string to almost all your `<input>` elements. Unfortunately, you later use the `parseInt()` function, which does not return a 0 for an empty string, but in fact NaN. I assigned a default value of 0 to all your `<input>` elements instead.

**JavaScript corrections:**

- You attempt to access the value of your `<input>` elements with `.options[elt.selectedIndex].value`. This is how you access the value of a `<select>` element - for an `<input type="number">`, just `.value` will suffice.
- You have a typo on what you are passing to `parseInt()`. Rather than passing the function the value of an `<input>`, you are passing the `<input>` itself. So instead of something like `parseInt(supthu1a)`, you should be using `parseInt(supthu1)`.

Your resultant code would thus look like:

```html
<form action='' method='post' name="Timesheet">
    <p>
        <label>Name</label>
        <br>
        <input type='text' name='name' value=''>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Employee Number:</label>
        <br>
        <input type='text' name='empnumber' value=''>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Department</label>
        <br>
        <input type='text' name='dept' value=''>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Pay Period Ending</label>
        <br>
        <input type='text' name='ppend' value=''>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        <label>Support</label>
        <br>
        <label>Thu</label>
        <input type='number' name='supthu1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supthu1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Fri</label>
        <input type='number' name='supfri1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supfri1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Sat</label>
        <input type='number' name='supsat1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supsat1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Mon</label>
        <input type='number' name='supmon1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supmon1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Tue</label>
        <input type='number' name='supteu1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="suptue1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Wed</label>
        <input type='number' name='supwed1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supwed1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Thu</label>
        <input type='number' name='supthu2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supthu2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Fri</label>
        <input type='number' name='supfri2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supfri2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Sat</label>
        <input type='number' name='supsat2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supsat2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Mon</label>
        <input type='number' name='supmon2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supmon2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Tue</label>
        <input type='number' name='suptue2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="suptue2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
        <label>Wed</label>
        <input type='number' name='supwed2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supwed2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value='0'>
    </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculateTime()">Calculate</button>Total Hours:
    <INPUT type="text" id="PicExtHours" Size=8 value='0'>
    <p>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
    </p>
</form>
```

```js
function calculateTime() {

    //Get selected data  
    var elt = document.getElementById("supthu1a");
    var supthu1 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supfri1a");
    var supfri1 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supsat1a");
    var supsat1 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supmon1a");
    var supmon1 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("suptue1a");
    var suptue1 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supwed1a");
    var supwed1 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supthu2a");
    var supthu2 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supfri2a");
    var supfri2 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supsat2a");
    var supsat2 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supmon2a");
    var supmon2 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("suptue2a");
    var suptue2 = elt.value;

    var elt = document.getElementById("supwed2a");
    var supwed2 = elt.value;


    //convert data to integers
    supthu1 = parseInt(supthu1);
    supfri1 = parseInt(supfri1);
    supsat1 = parseInt(supsat1);
    supmon1 = parseInt(supmon1);
    suptue1 = parseInt(suptue1);
    supwed1 = parseInt(supwed1);
    supthu2 = parseInt(supthu2);
    supfri2 = parseInt(supfri2);
    supsat2 = parseInt(supsat2);
    supmon2 = parseInt(supmon2);
    suptue2 = parseInt(suptue2);
    supwed2 = parseInt(supwed2);

    //calculate total value  
    var total = supthu1 + supfri1 + supsat1 + supmon1 + suptue1 + supwed1 + supthu2 + supfri2 + supsat2 + supmon2 + suptue2 + supwed2;

    //print value to  PicExtPrice 
    document.getElementById("PicExtHours").value = total;

}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9p40dhj/) to demonstrate. @Fnatte does provide a generally cleaner alternative, but I still felt it would be worthwhile (for your understanding) to explain why your original code was not working.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted tries to use the property *options* of each element. But that property is only available on [select elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement). The elements you select are of type *input*.

You also had some variable naming issues. For instance, see this part of your code:

```js
var supthu1 = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

// Then later :
supthu1 = parseInt(supthu1a); // <-- supthu1a is not defined
```

To further improve the code, I made the code less repetitive. Instead of writing parseInt multiple times, its better to use a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

```js
function calculateTime(){

  // Creating an array of all time field IDs
  var timeFieldIds = [
         "supthu1a", "supfri1a", "supsat1a", "supmon1a", 
         "suptue1a", "supwed1a", "supthu2a", "supfri2a",
         "supsat2a", "supmon2a", "suptue2a", "supwed2a"
  ];
  
  var total = 0;

  // Looping over the array of IDs
  for(var i = 0; i < timeFieldIds.length; i++) {
        // For each ID:

        // Select the element
        var el = document.getElementById(timeFieldIds[i]);

        // Get the value of the element and parse it as a integer.
        // " || 0" will make all invalid integers into zeroes.
        var val = parseInt(el.value) || 0;

        // Increase the total value
        total += val;
  }
  
  //print value to  PicExtPrice 
  document.getElementById("PicExtHours").value = total;

}
```

```html
<FORM Name="Timesheet">
  
<form action='' method='post'>
<p><label>Name</label><br><input type='text' name='name' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Employee Number:</label><br><input type='text' name='empnumber' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Department</label><br><input type='text' name='dept' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Pay Period Ending</label><br><input type='text' name='ppend' value=''></p> 
<br>
<p>
 
 <label>Support</label>
 <br>
 <label>Thu</label><input type='number' name='supthu1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supthu1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Fri</label><input type='number' name='supfri1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supfri1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Sat</label><input type='number' name='supsat1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supsat1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Mon</label><input type='number' name='supmon1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supmon1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Tue</label><input type='number' name='supteu1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="suptue1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Wed</label><input type='number' name='supwed1' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supwed1a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Thu</label><input type='number' name='supthu2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supthu2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Fri</label><input type='number' name='supfri2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supfri2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Sat</label><input type='number' name='supsat2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supsat2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Mon</label><input type='number' name='supmon2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supmon2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Tue</label><input type='number' name='suptue2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="suptue2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
 <label>Wed</label><input type='number' name='supwed2' onChange="calculateTime()" id="supwed2a" maxlength="3" size="3" value=''>
</p> 
</FORM>
<button type="button" onclick="calculateTime()">Calculate</button>
Total Hours:<INPUT type="text" id="PicExtHours" Size=8>
 
<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p> 
</form>
```